# Помогите считать с файла java 8 stream api

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, java-8, java-stream

Здравствуйте, подскажите как считать все слова из этого файла с стихотворением? То есть получить все слова без символов типа `#t_es1385_1`, цифровых символов, а также слова, содержащие в себе знаки препинания.

**Пытался сделать так:**

```
   Files.lines(Paths.get(ReadFile.class.getResource(path).toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    .map(s -> s.split("([^а-я А-Я]|[\\d\\w\\s])+"))
                    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Не получилось. Ниже само стихотворение:**

```
"Вот уж вечер. Роса…"

        Вот уж вечер. Роса: #t_es1385_1
        Блестит на крапиве.
        Я стою у дороги,
        Прислонившись к иве.

        От луны свет большой
        Прямо на нашу крышу.
        Где-то песнь соловья
        Вдалеке я слышу.

        Хорошо и тепло,
        Как зимой у печки.
        И березы стоят,
        Как большие свечки.

        И вдали за рекой,
        Видно, за опушкой,
        Сонный сторож стучит
        Мертвой колотушкой.

1910



"Там, где капустные грядки…"

        Там, где капустные грядки: #t_es1385_2
```

Comment: сделал вот так: 
Files.lines(Paths.get(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    .map(s -> s.split("([^а-я А-Я]|[\\d]|[\\w]|[\\s])+"))
                    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

это правильно?

Answer (score 3):

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
     .map(s -> s.split(" "))
     .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
     .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
     .filter(s -> !s.startsWith("#"))
     .filter(s -> !s.matches("\\d+"))
     .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\p{IsPunctuation}", ""))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Выводится вот так   "81968196819681968196819681968196Стозвоном"

Comment: я сделал вот так: Files.lines(Paths.get(ReadFile.class.getResource(path).toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    .map(s -> s.split("([^а-я А-Я]|[\\d\\w\\s])+"))
                    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

Это не правильно?

Comment: Я не вижу способа, которым можно получить такой результат на ваших входных данных.

Comment: Если решает вашу задачу, то правильно.